# I am installing HANA Studio and I have JDK 1.8 and JDK 1.7 downloaded. How do I point the HANA Studio install towards JDK 1.7?

Tags: java, hana

I am installing HANA Studio and I have JDK 1.8 and JDK 1.7 downloaded. I use JDK 1.8 for Eclipse and some other things I am working on however when I try to install HANA Studio through the SAP HANA Lifecycle Management application, I am met with an error saying that JDK 1.8 can be find and the others cannot.  Below are the scenarios I have gone through before attempting another reinstall...without a successful:

-Downloaded 1.6 and 1.7

-Deleted all JDK/JRE's in windows explorer, re-downloaded just 1.6 and 1.7

-gone into Control Panel > Java > Add JDK > navigated to 1.6

-gone into Control Panel > Java > Add JDK > navigated to 1.7

What else do you think I should try?  I need to get this within the next 2 days please.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add JAVA_HOME in your environment variable.
Then also add it %PATH% until bin directory.

And later check the same by opening command and running JAVA : This should list all the functions associated with the JAVA.

Then you can install HANA Studio

Answer (score 0):

Just add the "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin" to the path...

Start --> Right click computer --> Properties --> advanced systemsettings --> Enviroment variables --> path